# How to merge this two sql into one sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
select partnerid, count(distinct processId) balance_count
from mipay.operation_log
where date = '20180501' and source = 'api' and operation = 'pay'
group by partnerid and info like "%BANLANCE%" group by partnerid;
```

result:

```
partnerid    balance_count
    1              11
    2              13  

select partnerid, count(distinct processId) bankcard_count
from mipay.operation_log
where date = '20180501' and source = 'api' and operation = 'pay'
group by partnerid and info like "%BANKCARD%" group by partnerid;
```

result:

```
  partnerid    bankcard_count
    1              23
    2              17
```

I hope to get the following result by one sql

```
partnerid   balance_count  bankcard_count
    1            11              23
    2            17              17
```

Comment: Does MySQL really execute those invalid queries?!?

Answer (score 2):

Use `case` expressions to conditional aggregation:

```
select partnerid,
       count(distinct case when info like "%BANLANCE%" then processId end) balance_count,
       count(distinct case when info like "%BANKCARD%" then processId end) bankcard_count
from mipay.operation_log
where date = '20180501' and source = 'api' and operation = 'pay'
group by partnerid
```